# Why is using the != operator gives me a simple error in my python program?

Tags: python, maze

**Why using the != operator produces an error in my python program**

```
def TakeTurn():

    time.sleep(1.5)
    turning = input("You have reached a junction.\nDo you want to turn left (L), turn right (R) or go straight ahead(S)?")
    if turning != "L" :
        print ("Sorry, I didn't understand that")
    elif turning != "R" :
        print ("Sorry, I didn't understand that")
    elif turning != "S" :
        print ("Sorry, I didn't understand that")
    else:
        choice = randint (1,10)

    print (choice)
```

If I enter the letter L or R or S it `prints Sorry, I didn't understand that`

Thank you in advance for the help !!!

Comment: Please ask your question in the question, not the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a flaw in your logic. If you enter the letter "L", the first if condition will evaluate to False, which is good, but then the next if condition will evaluate to True, which is certainly not what you want! If you think about it more carefully, any character you enter will always meet one of these conditions.

What you really want is the following:

```
if turning not in ["L", "R", "S"]:
    print ("Sorry, I didn't understand that")
else:
    choice = randint (1,10)
    print(choice)
```

Comment: Thanks but how could I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is faulty, one of these ifs will always match, so it will always print I didn't understand.

If the letter is not 'L' the first if will trigger, if it is the second will trigger.

What you want is:

```
if turning != 'L' and turning != 'R' and turning != 'S':
    print "Sorry, I didn't understand that"
```

or better yet:

```
if turning in ['L', 'R', 'S']:
    # do stuff for turning
else:
    print "Sorry, I didn't understand that"
```